# Showing a relation is transitive

Tags: proof-verification, equivalence-relations

**Problem:**

Let $A = \{(a,b)\}$, determine whether the relation $R = \{(b,a)\}$ is transitive.

**Claim:**

No, $R$ is not transitive.

**Proof:**

Since $a,b\in A$ and $a\in R$ but $b,a\notin R$.

I am not sure if this is a sufficient proof. Any suggestions would help.

Comment: Do you mean $A = \{a, b\}$, a two element set containing $a$ and $b$, instead o the one element set $\{(a, b)\}$ containing the single ordered pair $(a, b)$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is transitive (with $A=\{a,b\}$). The definition is
$$\forall a,b,c\in A: aRb \wedge bRc\Rightarrow aRc$$
where $R\subseteq A\times A$.

The point is that if the premise is not fulfilled, the relation is transitive (since then the implication becomes true).
For instance, $R=\{(a,b)\}$ (where $A=\{a,b\}$) and $R=\{(a,b),(a,c)\}$ are all transitive, but $R=\{(a,b),(b,c)\}$ is not since $(a,c)$ is missing.